# Where are default LS_COLORS set in RHEL 5.x?

Tags: terminal, redhat, rhel, ls-colors

In a terminal in Red Hat Enterprise Linux 5.x, running:

```
[$] Env
```

returns (among other things):

```
"LS_COLORS=no=00:fi=00:di=01;34:ln=01;36:pi=40;33 . . ."
```

Most of the content in `LS_COLORS` I find in the file:

```
/etc/DIR_COLORS
```

BUT the values "`no=00:fi=00:di=01;34:ln=01;36:pi=40;33` etc.", I have no success finding, even after grepping through the system.

In what file(s) are these values defined?

Yes, I know I can set the content of `LS_COLORS` to the values I please,
but what I wonder about is **where** the values above are **defined**.

Answer (score 9):

I think what you are looking for can be found at `/etc/profile.d/colorls.sh`:

```
# color-ls initialization

alias ll='ls -l' 2>/dev/null
alias l.='ls -d .*' 2>/dev/null

COLORS=/etc/DIR_COLORS
[ -e "/etc/DIR_COLORS.$TERM" ] && COLORS="/etc/DIR_COLORS.$TERM"
[ -e "$HOME/.dircolors" ] && COLORS="$HOME/.dircolors"
[ -e "$HOME/.dir_colors" ] && COLORS="$HOME/.dir_colors"
[ -e "$HOME/.dircolors.$TERM" ] && COLORS="$HOME/.dircolors.$TERM"
[ -e "$HOME/.dir_colors.$TERM" ] && COLORS="$HOME/.dir_colors.$TERM"
[ -e "$COLORS" ] || return

eval `dircolors --sh "$COLORS" 2>/dev/null`
[ -z "$LS_COLORS" ] && return

if ! egrep -qi "^COLOR.*none" $COLORS >/dev/null 2>/dev/null ; then
        alias ll='ls -l --color=tty' 2>/dev/null
        alias l.='ls -d .* --color=tty' 2>/dev/null
        alias ls='ls --color=tty' 2>/dev/null
fi
```

The `LS_COLORS` variable is set by an evaluation of the output of `dircolors --sh "$COLORS" 2>/dev/null`, which in turn receives its values from `/etc/DIR_COLORS`. So in other words, the values in `LS_COLORS` are identical to `DIR_COLORS` by default.

You can prove this by comparing the output from `dircolors --sh "$COLORS"`:

```
$ dircolors --sh "$COLORS" 
LS_COLORS='no=00:fi=00:di=01;34:ln=01;36:pi=40;33:so=01;35:bd=40;33;01:cd=40;33;01:or=01;05;37;41:mi=01;05;37;41:ex=01;32:*.cmd=01;32:*.exe=01;32:*.com=01;32:*.btm=01;32:*.bat=01;32:*.sh=01;32:*.csh=01;32:*.tar=01;31:*.tgz=01;31:*.arj=01;31:*.taz=01;31:*.lzh=01;31:*.zip=01;31:*.z=01;31:*.Z=01;31:*.gz=01;31:*.bz2=01;31:*.bz=01;31:*.tz=01;31:*.rpm=01;31:*.cpio=01;31:*.jpg=01;35:*.gif=01;35:*.bmp=01;35:*.xbm=01;35:*.xpm=01;35:*.png=01;35:*.tif=01;35:';
export LS_COLORS
```

And `echo $LS_COLORS`:

```
$ echo $LS_COLORS
no=00:fi=00:di=01;34:ln=01;36:pi=40;33:so=01;35:bd=40;33;01:cd=40;33;01:or=01;05;37;41:mi=01;05;37;41:ex=01;32:*.cmd=01;32:*.exe=01;32:*.com=01;32:*.btm=01;32:*.bat=01;32:*.sh=01;32:*.csh=01;32:*.tar=01;31:*.tgz=01;31:*.arj=01;31:*.taz=01;31:*.lzh=01;31:*.zip=01;31:*.z=01;31:*.Z=01;31:*.gz=01;31:*.bz2=01;31:*.bz=01;31:*.tz=01;31:*.rpm=01;31:*.cpio=01;31:*.jpg=01;35:*.gif=01;35:*.bmp=01;35:*.xbm=01;35:*.xpm=01;35:*.png=01;35:*.tif=01;35:
```

And there you have it.

Answer (score 3):

```
  /etc/DIR_COLORS
```

The above one is not the same as the following.

```
 /etc/DIR_COLORS.xterm.
```

When logged with SSH terminal file

```
/etc/DIR_COLORS.xterm
```

is used.

Answer (score 0):

from 'dircolors' manpage ::

> If  FILE  is  specified,  read it to
>   determine which colors to use for
>   which file types and
>   extensions.Otherwise, a precompiled
>   database is used.  For details on the
>   format of these files, run `dircolors
>   --print-database'.

so it seems like those codes are compiled in the system